# How to get this visual effect in video from a sound file?

Tags: video, video-processing, soundeffect, video-effects

Does anyone know how I can get the same, or similar, visual effect from a sound file, which is produced in this teaser (see 51 seconds out in the video): 
http://vaxxedthemovie.com/stream/

Answer (score 0):

I got feedback from people involved in making the documentary Vaxxed - From Cover-Up to Catastrophe. Here is the relevant text: 
It's created by a plug-in (additional software) for Adobe After Effects  and it's called "Particular", made by a company called Trapcode: https://www.redgiant.com/products/trapcode-particular/

BUT... this is only working for After Effects, which I do not have. 
So if anyone know about a similar effects tool, which work standalone, or with Premiere Pro, or eventually with DaVinci Resolve, then please write about it here.

Comment: _"..then please write about it here."_ how is this even a **programming** question? Maybe you want to ask at [**Video Production**](https://video.stackexchange.com/) or even try [**Software Recommends**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). Ask here if you're programming your own Particular effects (pixel editing) and are also getting errors like a stack or buffer overflow etc etc...